How to change legend display to circle?
I've tried everything, but I couldn't change the legend display to be round. I've tried all options again! HighChart.stockChart
I tried the following, but the rounding doesn't work; only width and height adjustments work, despite trying a bunch of different methods
legend: {
  enabled: true,
  align: 'left',
  x: -5,
  itemHiddenStyle: {
    color: '#666',
    textDecoration: 'none'
  },
  itemStyle: {
    fontSize: '16px'
  },
  symbol: 'circle',
  symbolWidth: 30,
  symbolHeight: 30,
  symbolRadius: 10,


},


Highcharts allows you to define a different symbol for each legend item and that is why this setting is located at the series level:
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      legendSymbol: 'rectangle'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    symbolWidth: 15,
    symbolHeight: 15,
    symbolRadius: 15
  }


Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g4z67mcj/
API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.legendSymbol

Thank you so much! What would I do without you!
